# how to get actual path of a file picked in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

how to get actual path of a file picked in jetpack compose and upload in via retrofit.i had tried to get path via content resolver but it returning "ERROR: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is correctly initialized before accessing data"

Comment: I think we are going to need more details in order to provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: when i pick file from the external storage  i am getting uri as document/document:301522 like this how to get actual path of that file